# derivative of volterra operator with respect to f?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

What is the derivative of volterra operator with respect to $f$?(Also Higher Order Derivatives)

$(V f)(x)=‎\int_0^x f(t)dt.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your function space is the space of continuous functions as is often the case with the Volterra operator. (If $L^2([0,1])$ is meant, just apply Cauchy-Schwarz to $f$ and $g$ where $g(x) = 1$ and you get that it is again bounded.) The Volterra operator is bounded on $C([0,1])$ since:

$$|Vf(x)| \le \int_0^x|f(t)|\,dt \le \left(\sup_{y\in[0,1]}|f(y)|\right)\int_0^x\,dt \le \|f\|\int_0^x\,dt \le \|f\|. $$

The last equality holds because $x \le 1$. For an operator $F$, the Frechet derivative exists if and only if there exists a bounded operator $A$ such that

$$F(x+h) = Fx + Ah + o(\|h\|).$$

Moreover, $A$ is said to be the Frechet derivative of $F$. If $F$ is itself bounded and linear, then we have that

$$F(x+h) = Fx + Fh.$$

In your case, the Volterra operator is bounded and linear. What then would you say about $V$ and its relationship to $A$?

Answer (score 0):

For sufficiently well behaved functions(smooth and sufficiently differentiable for the expressions to make sense), the derivative is 
$$f(x)-f(0)$$ and the higher derivatives 
$$
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(Vf(x) = \frac{d^{n-1}f}{dx^{n-1}}
$$

Comment: This isn't what is being asked. It's a variational-type question, not a standard calculus question.